# Site cannot be reached after login in magento backend

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento-1.9

I tried to set-up new magento site on Apache (2.4.18). My current PHP version is 7.0.8 and using Ubuntu 16.04. Everything work fine except backend login. When I tried to key-in admin username and password, it shown site cannot be reached. I think, I might configured wrongly on Apache. Here my config file!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html
     <Directory /var/www/html/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/exampl_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My Login screen is here!

[image]

After login, it was shown like that;

[image]

I already tried to clear cookie path in **core_config_data** and cache file under **/var/cache/**

Comment: Doesn't look like there's anything wrong with your site's apache config, maybe your installation of magento went bad?

Comment: I just downloaded all code from Git. I tried too many time with other staging sever (nginx). But, I faced this problem on Apache. I'm sure Apache problem or PHP 7 problem.

Comment: @Epodax, Yes, that's my fault. I set web/unsecure/base_url was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my problems after upgrading PHP7 with Magento 1.9.0.2

Today (27-Oct-2016 9:55AM Singapore Time), I tried to test Magento 1.9.2 on PHP 7.

Here my initial problems with php 7.

1. Admin Login redirect login page (solved by comment
   **$this->renewSession();** under **app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php** or you can override this class file with magento recommended way)
2. Customer cannot create (**Decoding Error
       in Zend_Json::decode()**) function
3. Tax Calculation wrong
4. Coupon code calculation wrong
5. And a lot more unseen problems

So, I realized that all these solution are not sustainable way with php 7 and Magento 1x

My personal recommendation –

Downgrade to PHP5.6. Bad news is 1x slower than PHP 7.